# languages with functions that do not need parentheses?

Tags: programming-languages, function, parentheses

IIRC, vb6 allowed function calls with no ().  IIRC, it was allowed whenever the func didn't have a return value, and you could always use func(same, params, here).

What other languages allow this? What do you think func with no parentheses should mean? What are the rules for them?

Disclaimer:  I am designing a language, so if you are and will be upset if I took the idea, then please don't write it.

Comment: Surely this was a "feature" of VB6 that was universally hated?

Comment: er, Neil, speak for yourself mate. I for one like clean syntax...

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much all functional languages from the ML lineage (Miranda, Haskell, OCML, F#, SML, etc.) don't require parentheses for function calls.

For example, in Haskell:

```
Prelude> (\x->x) 1
1
```

The anonymous identity function is called with 1 and returns 1

Answer (score 5):

[Tcl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl#Syntax_and_Fundamental_Semantics)

```
puts "Hello, world!"
```

Answer (score 4):

[Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) and [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) are a couple of examples. (Note that both *allow* parantheses, but they do not *require* them in all situations.)

Answer (score 3):

**Ruby**

```
def hello_world name
   puts "Hello world, #{name}."
end

hello_world 'Hal'
```

If you want you **can** but you're not forced to use parentheses, which is great
in the cases where it increases readability and decreases ambiguity.

Comment: You require parentheses sometimes, but only in cases where it would be otherwise impossible for the interpreter to figure out the correct ordering of arguments in a long chain of argument calls.

Answer (score 3):

[Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) is a great language that compiles into Javascript and doesn't require parentheses, even for nested method calls.

For example:

```coffee
y = Math.pow 10, Math.floor Math.log10 x
```

becomes:

```js
var y = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(x)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is another language that allows, but does not require (in most cases), parentheses on method calls.

They are also optional when defining a method.

```
def say_hi your_name
  puts "Hello, #{your_name}!"
end
```

When a method is an argument for another method, Ruby 1.8.* gives a warning about requiring parentheses in a future version. Try to make sense of this, then try it in irb:

```
puts "guess what this does?".slice 6, 4
```

Comment: Slice, then puts. To puts the slice function along with the integers, i guess you need another comma.

Answer (score 2):

In functional programming languages (ML, Haskell, F#, OCAML), any function just has one argument - Multi-parameter-functions are represented by passing tuples or [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Thus there is no need for a function to enclose the parameter in parentheses.

Ex #1:

```
inc x = x + 1
res = inc 42
```

Ex #2:

```
sum a b = a + b
res = sum 1 2
```

In #2, you pass `1` to `sum` and then call the resulting function with `2` (Currying)

Additionally, you can use mechanims like function composition, pipelines or the $-operator ([point-free style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming)).

Just compare the two examples.

```
a = f(g x)
b = f $ g x

print(square(parse "Hello"))
"Hello" |> parse |> square |> print
```

Another way of reducing parentheses in other languages is introducing extension methods (similar to pipelines) or the arrow-operator.

Compare:

```
ToString(Parse(42))
"42".Parse().ToString()

(*(*SomePointer).SomeMember).Invoke();
SomePointer->SomeMember->Invoke();
```

Ruby and Perl allow subroutines to be called without parentheses, VBC-style languages (Visual Basic, VBScript) do this too.
Lisp/Scheme don't need parentheses for their function calls too (but there are many parentheses anyway^^)

Answer (score 1):

Perl:

```
To call subroutines:

NAME(LIST);    # & is optional with parentheses.
NAME LIST;     # Parentheses optional if predeclared/imported.
&NAME(LIST);   # Circumvent prototypes.
&NAME;     # Makes current @_ visible to called subroutine.
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html

Answer (score 1):

F# doesn't need parameters - in particular when using the pipeline operator.

```
a(b(c(d(10)))) ;;
```

is equivalent to:

```
10 |> d |> c |> b |> a ;;
```

(a similar effect to extension methods, really)

---

In Ruby, the brackets are always optional (similar to VB) - but in Ruby they are even optional when **declaring** a method:

```
def echo( foo )
    return foo
end
```

is identical to:

```
def echo foo
    return foo
end
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is an example for what a function "call" without parens can mean: reference. In languages that allow treating functions as objects, a function name is just another variable.

Also, in PHP language constructs (like echo or exit) don't need parens even if they take arguments, so "echo $foo" means the same as "echo($foo)" and "exit $foo" means the same as "exit($foo)".

Comment: A reference to a JS function (without parens) is specifically _not_ a call.

Answer (score 1):

**Forth**

```
: STAR          [CHAR] * EMIT ;
: STARS         0 DO STAR LOOP CR ;
: SQUARE        DUP 0 DO DUP STARS LOOP DROP ;
: TRIANGLE      1 DO I STARS LOOP ;
: TOWER ( n -- )  DUP TRIANGLE SQUARE ;
```

Parenthesis are comments.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell functions do not require parentheses around arguments for function calls. This causes a lot of confusion though:

```
function test($a,$b) {
write-host $a
}

test(1,2)
```

The above prints:
1 2

(because `(1,2)` is an array in Powershell and that is passed to $a)

But the thing is method calls ( on objects) requires parentheses

Answer (score 0):

A couple of examples of non-traditional or no parenthesis use:

Objective-C: `[object functionNamePart1:arg1 functionNamePart2:arg2]`
or: `[object function]`

F-Script (based on objective-C): `object functionNamePart1:arg1 functionNamePart2:arg2`
or: `object function`

Lisp: `(+ 2 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Haskell does not require parentheses too.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.madore.org/~david/programs/unlambda/

Unlambda curries functions together with the ` symbol, so it doesn't use parentheses.